# sh-mode: Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely",

Tags: sh-mode

Generate a file with this:

```
(echo '#!/bin/bash'
echo 'myfunc() {'
echo "cat <<'z'"
seq 135
echo zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
echo z
echo '}') >out
```

Open it in Emacs. When pressing `C-M-f` I get the error:

```
Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely", 515, 515
```

Then I press `M->` to get to end of file, `C-x C-x` to move back to where I came from, and now I can press `C-M-f` and move to the next sexp.

It is as if emacs does not really index the full file before I have been to the end of the file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 4):

Made a bug report for this: 
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30726

Bug-source is in but-last line of the def in lisp.el, where

(goto-char (or (scan-sexps (point) arg) (buffer-end arg)))

`scan-sexps` sends the error.

Wrapping it into `(ignore-errors`:

```
(or (ignore-errors (scan-sexps (point) arg))...
```

makes it gone.

Error showed up when `forward-sexp` was called from closing parenthesis at last line of example code. Seen from emitting `scan-sexps` that error might be justified, however `forward-sexp` should deal with it. There may be more occasions to fail. IMHO `forward-sexp` navigates strangely from inside a string - try it at a functions docstring.

To avoid these wrote 
    `ar-forward-sexp`

which see here: https://github.com/andreas-roehler/thingatpt-utils-core/blob/master/ar-subr.el

Comment: Does this just ignore the error or does it fix it, so that it now works as if I have done `M-> C-x C-x` first?

Comment: @OleTange Updated the answer to be more informative.